# ndarray to table (from step function result)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am working on survival function, and as an output I get this probability in ndarray

```
   array([StepFunction(x=array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
       34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47]), y=array([9.17296785e-01, 8.58509959e-01, 7.95751449e-01, 7.23932861e-01,
       6.72942004e-01, 6.18755675e-01, 5.57276831e-01, 5.13920939e-01,
       4.68160907e-01, 4.16574744e-01, 3.80432714e-01, 3.42539970e-01,
       3.00064379e-01, 2.70472496e-01, 2.39721587e-01, 2.05666153e-01,
       1.82207637e-01, 1.58125975e-01, 1.31987128e-01, 1.14216290e-01,
       9.63014259e-02, 7.73126310e-02, 6.47332309e-02, 5.23714045e-02,
       3.96594097e-02, 3.14924449e-02, 2.37709655e-02, 1.70021158e-02,
       1.30073223e-02, 9.69078403e-03, 6.66962927e-03, 4.98463919e-03,
       3.47434981e-03, 2.20675133e-03, 1.50212153e-03, 9.34847760e-04,
       5.32180234e-04, 3.43887595e-04, 1.95095396e-04, 1.02772900e-04,
       5.78492414e-05, 3.44687086e-05, 1.84070989e-05, 8.30616036e-06,
       2.61503613e-06, 5.73250479e-07, 6.00917151e-08, 2.59960925e-09]))],
      dtype=object)
```

and I want to transform this result to some table like this, with column x, y1, y2, etc(did it manually to show example)

[image: expected table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to convert a numpy array to an xls file? If so one way would be to get help from Pandas facilities.

```
import pandas as pd

## convert your array into a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame (array)

## save to xlsx file

filepath = 'my_excel_file.xlsx'

df.to_excel(filepath, index=False)
```

Comment: thanks I tried to convert the array to pd data frame but it converted all data into one data point only, probably because the result has the word 'StepFunction' on its default?

Comment: Where does the output come from? Are you calling a library or own code? If the former, what library exactly?

Comment: I am noticing that dtype above is an object.

Comment: I used scikit-survival and actually found out that it was an array before it got transform to stepfuction so now all good! thanks for helping!

Comment: Hi @npm, how did you do it? The step function formatted result came from estimator.predict_survival_function(x). I am looking forward to get the probability at particular days